# Is it possible to make stackdriver monitoring NOT fill time-series gaps when aggregating

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to aggregate 2 time-series that are aligned in time (i.e., the time periods for which these series have values are identical) by computing their maximum value.

This aggregation works fine for time periods in which the original series have values. However, for time periods in which the original series don't have values (i.e., both have gaps), the aggregation provides a value nevertheless, such that the gaps disappear. Is it possible to avoid this behavior and keep the gaps in the aggregation result as well?

I'm using the Metrics Explorer to build this query. The source of the query is a StackDriver metric that I'm aggregating with the 'max' aggregation. I have the alignment period set to 1 m (the default) and the aligner set to 'max' as well. There is no secondary aggregation.

Comment: there is `NONE` aligner https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#Aligner , but its not available when cross-aggregating (and not available via UI), also you might consider checking MetricAbsence API https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#metricabsence